# How to prefer one authentication scheme over another?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I have two JwtBearer schemes, each one can use cookie in addition to authorization header

```
.AddJwtBearer(OAuthSchemeConstants.SchemeName, options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = oauthServerUrl;
                    options.AutomaticRefreshInterval = new TimeSpan(24, 0, 0);
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateAudience = false,
                        ValidateIssuer = true,
                        ValidIssuer = oauthServerUrl,
                        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
                        NameClaimType = AuthenticationConstants.NameClaimType,
                    };

                    options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
                    {
                        OnMessageReceived = (context) =>
                        {
                            var authHeader = context.Request.GetAuthorizationHeader();
                            var authCookie = context.Request.GetCookie(OAuthSchemeConstants.CookieName);

                            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(authHeader) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(authCookie))
                            {
                                context.Token = authCookie;
                            }

                            return Task.CompletedTask;
                        },
                    }
                });

.AddJwtBearer(CustomSchemeConstants.SchemeName, options =>
                {
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                    options.SaveToken = true;
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                        IssuerSigningKey = signingKey,
                        ValidateIssuer = false,
                        ValidateAudience = false,
                        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
                        NameClaimType = AuthenticationConstants.NameClaimType
                    };

                    options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
                    {
                        OnMessageReceived = (context) =>
                        {
                            var authHeader = context.Request.GetAuthorizationHeader();
                            var authCookie = context.Request.GetCookie(CustomSchemeConstants.CookieName);

                            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(authHeader) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(authCookie))
                            {
                                context.Token = authCookie;
                            }

                            return Task.CompletedTask;
                        }
                    };
                });
```

When cookies for both schemes are present, I want to prefer `OAuthSchemeConstants.SchemeName` over `CustomSchemeConstants.SchemeName`.

My default authorization policy looks like this:

```
            var policyBuilder = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(
                OAuthSchemeConstants.SchemeName,
                CustomSchemeConstants.SchemeName
            );

            policyBuilder = policyBuilder.RequireAuthenticatedUser();

            return policyBuilder.Build();
```

What I tried:

- setting options.DefaultAuthenticationScheme / options.DefaultChallengeScheme to OAuthSchemeConstants.SchemeName in .AddAuthentication()
- change order in which schemes are added to authentication builder
- change order of schemes in AuthorizationPolicyBuilder

But no matter what, when cookies for both schemes are present, CustomSchemeConstants.SchemeName is being used for authentication.

I need this because I am migrating authentication scheme to OAuthSchemeConstants.SchemeName and I need both schemes to be working but prefer OAuthSchemeConstants.SchemeName over CustomSchemeConstants.SchemeName.

CustomSchemeConstants.SchemeName is just "MyCustomScheme" and OAuthSchemeConstants.SchemeName is just "MyOAuthScheme".

So when both schemes are "valid" (valid jwts in cookies are present for both schemes) how I can control which scheme is being used for authentication?

Comment: Check out ForwardDefaultSelector on the authentication scheme options. You can set a function there that can return a different scheme's name based on e.g. request headers.

Comment: Hey, it worked but the problem is that now when JWT in scheme A expired and scheme B makes forward-default to A if there is a cookie for scheme A present, then whole validation fails and 401 is returned. Normally, without using default selector if any of JWTs is expired, and the other one is not then the other one is used for authentication. I am wondering what makes one scheme as a default in first place.